# Recursive maze generation

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I accidentally posted this question on a different account of mine, so I deleted the post and reposted on this account.

So I wanted to create a maze generation algorithm for fun, but I hit a bit of a bump. The algorithm I wrote puts in spaces that are unreachable and that have no exit. What could the problem be?

Here is what I mean

```
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
# . . . . . # . # . . . # . # . # . . . # 
# . # # # . # . # # # . # # # . # # # # # 
# . . . # . # . # . . . . . # . . . . . # 
# # # . # . # . # # # # # . # # # . # # # 
# . . . # . # . . . . . # . # . # . # . # 
# . # # # . # # # # # . # # # . # . # . # 
# . # . # . . . . . # . . . . . . . # . # 
# . # . # . # # # # # # # . # # # . # # # 
# . # . # . . . . . . . # . . . # . # . # 
# . # . # # # # # # # . # . # . # # # . # 
# . # . # . . . . . . . # . # . # . . . # 
# # # # # . # # # # # # # . # . # . # # # 
# . # . . . # . . . . . . . # . # . # . # 
# . # # # . # . # # # # # # # # # . # # # 
# . . . # . . . # . # . . . . . . . # . # 
# # # . # # # . # # # # # # # . # # # . # 
# . # . # . . . . . # . . . # . . . . . # 
# # # . # . # # # . # . # # # . # # # . # 
# . # . . . # . # . # . # . . . . . # . # 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

And this is my code
Description:
Create a maze consisting of entirely connected cells. As stated 0 up, 1 down, 2 right, 3 left, orientTo records whether the dfs went up/down/left/right to get to the current cell.
In the mazeGen function: generate the cell you came from, now remove the wall between current cell and last cell. Generate all neighbours of current cell and randomly arrange them into an array, array holds x,y, and which way the dfs moved to get to this neighbour cell. Now iterate through this array and recursively call the dfs with these neighbour values.

Comment: Why do you have multiple accounts?

Comment: By deleting, you lost my comment. I'll say it again: I haven't checked what else is wrong, but your "randomly arrange" may put the same neighbor into multiple slots and I doubt that's what you intended. Shuffle.

Comment: It was an accident, I was on programmers.stackexchange and I pressed sign in with facebook, which made a completely new account, then the post got migrated here. So I just deleted it and reposted.

Comment: Also keshlam, does it really? I am asking this because the if(points[j][0]..... line makes sure that it doesn't, because it checks if the entry has already been added in another spot.

Comment: ... OK, you may be right. It's a sorta inside-out way of doing what you want to do, but...

Comment: Note that you could've and can still just [merge the accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that maze spaces (non-walls) should make a tree. That means, all spaces connected and there is only one path between each pair of spaces.

Since tree doesn't have a cycle, it is possible to create a maze by breaking any cycle found. It can be done by finding cycles (DFS) and setting any space that is in detected cycle to be a wall till there is no cycles. It can be done in one DFS pass. Creation of different mazes is done by choosing different starting space and randomly choosing neighbour to proceed.

Comment: So basically flood fill all the spaces and if some portions aren't flooded you choose a random wall cell, and break it?

Comment: Yes, randomly flood fill spaces and if filling finds already flooded cell then set a wall on cell from where filling is going on flooded cell.

Comment: This seems like a lot more work than it should be for a maze generation algorithm, isn't there a way to incorporate this kind of logic into the dfs? Like so that it never creates enclosed spaces.

Comment: Wiki has good description and nice [video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Depth-first_search).

Comment: Yea I got it, I just changed up the order of the code, and deleted the parameter that records the last visited cell. Now it generates the next cells.